# How does #import work in iOS' UI Automation?

Tags: javascript, ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I'm making a small test framework that uses the JavaScript module pattern for UI Automation testing on iOS. However, I seem to be getting odd results based on [#import](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Built-InInstruments/Built-InInstruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH6-SW75) and extending modules.

I have the base test module called `Tester-Module.js`:

```
(function() {
  var Tester = this.Tester = {};

  Tester.setUp = function() {
    UIALogger.logMessage('Regular SetUp()');
  }
}).call(this);
```

If I import this module in my test case, it works fine. Here's the test file `tester.js` (`tester.js` is the file I import in Instruments):

```
#import "./Tester-Module.js"

// Prints 'Regular SetUp()'
Tester.setUp();
```

However, if I try to extend the `Tester-Module.js` module in another module file, I cannot reference the Tester object. `Tester-Extension.js` extends the Tester module defined in `Tester-Module.js`:

```
#import "./Tester-Module.js"

// Outputs:
// Exception raised while running script:
// ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Tester\n
Tester.setUp = function() {
  UIALogger.logMessage('Overwritten SetUp()');
}
```

And the updated test case file `tester.js`:

```
#import "./Tester-Extension.js"

// Exception is thrown before this
Tester.setUp();
```

My hopefully related questions are:

- Why can I not reference the Tester object inside `Tester-Extension.js`, but can in `tester.js`?
- What is the #import macro doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more searching and testing, it looks like using `#import` in each module file — similar to require in Node.js — is not supported with the UI Automation framework.

The work around is to include a header file that imports every module and then just import that in the test case. Using the example above, the header file would look like:

```
// Tester-Header.js
#import "./Tester-Module.js"
#import "./Tester-Extension.js"
```

And the test file would simply import the header file like so:

```
#import "./Tester-Header.js"

// Prints "Overwritten SetUp()"
Tester.setUp();
```

The [Mother May UI](https://github.com/baalexander/Mother-May-UI) BDD framework has a more extensive example of a [header file](https://github.com/baalexander/Mother-May-UI/blob/master/mother-ios.js) and importing the header file into a [test file](https://github.com/baalexander/Mother-May-UI/blob/master/examples/ios/Car%20Lot/UI%20Tests/tests.js). Disclosure: I wrote the framework and originally asked this question in order to make the framework more modular.